# Scapy not showing HTTP responses

Tags: python, http, scapy

I am running the HTTP extension to Scapy from [here](https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http). This is what I did:

1. Started scapy and did `sniff(filter="tcp",count=100)`
2. Opened a browser and searched for an image
3. Came back to Scapy and did `a=_` and `if HTTPResponse in a:
   print a.show()`

It seems that there are no HTTPResponse packets, which is impossible since I see responses in the browser. Why does this happen?

Comment: Could you please post your entire code? I'm not going to ask your question, I just want to see a full example of it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sniff` return a vector of packets, on which you need to iterate and check if each packet has the HTTP layer you are looking for:

```
a = sniff(...)
for packet in a:
    if HTTPResponse in packet:
        packet.show()
```

This should work.